# Why the size of struct A is not equal size of struct B with same fields?

Tags: c#

Why the size of `struct A` is not equal size of `struct B`?

And what I need to do, they will the same size?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        struct A
        {
            char a;
            char c;
            int b;
        }

        struct B
        {
            char a;
            int b;
            char c;

        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            unsafe
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sizeof(A));
                Console.WriteLine(sizeof(B));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output is :

```
8
12
```

Comment: It is due to padding rules.  Relevant SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sizeof operator gives extra size of a struct in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960311/sizeof-operator-gives-extra-size-of-a-struct-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 9):

There are some paddings among fields. Padding is calculated using previous fields and next field.

Also, this condition should be true:

```
(size of struct) % (size of largest type) == 0
```

In your case the largest type is `int` and its size is `4` bytes.

```
struct A
{
    char a; // size is 2, no previous field, next field size is 2 - no alignment needed
    char c; // size is 2, previous size is 2 -> 2 + 2 = 4, next size is 4 - no alignment needed
    int b;  //size is 4, it is last field, size is 4 + 4 = 8.  

    //current size is 2 + 2 + 4 = 8
    //8 % 4 == 0 - true - 8 is final size
}

struct B
{
    char a; // size is 2, next size is 4, alignment needed - 2 -> 4, size of this field with alignment is 4
    int b;  // size is 4, previous is 4, next size is 2(lower) - no alignment needed
    char c; // size is 2, previous is 4 + 4 = 8 - no alignment needed

    //current size is 4 + 4 + 2 = 10
    //but size should be size % 4 = 0 -> 10 % 4 == 0 - false, adjust to 12
}
```

If you want same size for two structs you can use `LayoutKind.Explicit`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct A
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    char a;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    char c;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    int b;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct B
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    char a;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    int b;

    [FieldOffset(6)]
    char c;
}
```

**OR**

You can use `LayoutKind.Sequential`, `Pack = 1` and `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` to get size 8.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct A
{
    char a;
    char c;
    int b;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct B
{        
    char a;
    int b;
    char c;
}
```

Also, you can get struct size without `unsafe`:

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(A)));
Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(B)));
```

Comment: @seyxsultan, I don't know what is the best way, but with `LayoutKind.Sequential` I get different sizes.

Comment: @seyxsultan, Whick size do you get? If you get size 6 - it is wrong size - you have two `char` variables 2 byte each and `int` variable, size is `2+2+4=8`

Comment: I get 8  for both

Comment: @seyxsultan, I get `size  == 6` , but anyway, it is good if it works for you, thanks for reply

Comment: [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        struct A
        {
            char a;
            char c;
            int b;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,  Pack = 1)]
        struct B
        {
            char a;
            int b;
            char c;
           
        }

Comment: @seyxsultan, try to print size using `Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(A)));`

Comment: Is there a reason why compiler doesn't automatically move variables around to save as much memory as possible?

Comment: @FCin, see here: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/

Answer (score 7):

It's because your compiler reserves the right to insert *padding* between the members of the `struct`, plus some space at the end. (But note that padding is **not** allowed before the first member.)

It does this in order to align the start of members on easily-addressable memory locations.

In particular, a compiler is likely to insert padding between a single `char` and an `int`. An even number of `char`s followed by an `int` may well therefore take up less space than a `char` followed by an `int` followed by an odd number of `char`s.

Comment: I believe that's down to a particular C# implementation. (For what it's worth the equivalent feature exists in C and C++ for many compilers, despite not being part of the standard requirements for those languages.). Perhaps ask that as a more targeted question?

Answer (score 6):

This is a processor implementation detail, one that .NET tries very hard to hide.  Variables need have a storage location that allows the processor to read and write the value with a single data bus operation.  That makes the *alignment* of the variable address very important.  Reading a single byte is never a problem.  But a short (2 bytes) should have an address that is a multiple of 2.  An int (4 bytes) should have an address that is a multiple of 4.  Ideally a long or double (8 bytes) have an address that is a multiple of 8, but that cannot always be achieved, not on a 32-bit processor.

Intel and AMD processors allow unaligned reads and writes, unlike RISC cores.  But that can come at a cost, it might require two data bus cycles to read two chunks of bytes, part of the upper bytes of a value and part of the lower bytes.  With a circuit that shuffles those bytes into the right place.  That takes time, typically an extra 1 to 3 clock cycles.  Lots and lots of time on a RISC core to handle the bus error trap.

But more severely, it breaks the .NET memory model.  It provides an atomicity guarantee for simple value types and object references.  Unaligned reads and writes break that promise.  It might cause *tearing*, observing part of the bytes being written.  And much worse, it can break the garbage collector.  The GC relies heavily on an object reference being updated atomically.

So when the CLR determines the layout of a structure or class, it must ensure the alignment requirement is met.  And if it is not then it needs to leave extra unused space between the variables.  And perhaps extra space at the end to ensure members are still aligned when stored in an array.  Generic word for that extra space is "padding".

Specific to a class declaration, it has [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)], it can shuffle the members around to achieve the best layout.  Not a struct, they are LayoutKind.Sequential by default.  Beyond classes and structs, this alignment guarantee is also required for static variables and the arguments and local variables of a method.  But not nearly as easily observed.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the fields is different; I would guess that the size is different as the members are padded (i.e. located in such a way that they begin on an even machine word in order to make access easier at the cost of memory consumption).